# Does $\mathbb{Q} \times $ Cantor set have a complete sequence of $\sigma$-discrete closed covers?

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers, filters, cantor-set

Does the space $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathcal{C}$ possess a complete sequence of $\sigma$-discrete closed covers?

I am interested in this question, because if answered positively, the Theorem 1 in the [paper by Junnila & Künzi](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/127398/CzechMathJ_48-1998-1_5.pdf) could be used to characterize the space $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathcal{C}$ .

But I am not sure whether this has been answered, haven´t found it in any literature.

**Definitions**

If $S \subseteq P(X)$ for a topological space $X$, then we say that $S$ is **$\sigma$-discrete** if $S = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} S_{n}$ where each $S_n$ is discrete.

$\mathbb{Q}\times\mathcal{C}$ = Product of rational numbers and the Cantor set

**Complete sequence of covers:** A sequence $(Fn)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
of covers of a topo. space $X$ is said to be complete, if every filter
which intersects all $F_n$´s has an accumulation point in $X$.

Filter on X = family of subsets of X, which is closed with respect to supersets and finite intersections and does not contain the empty set

A point $x \in X$ is said to be an accumulation point of a filter $F$ on X, if each neighborhood of $x$ intersects each element of $F$.

Comment: I took the freedom to switch Cantor set notation to $\mathcal C$ to avoid confusion with the set of complex numbers.

Comment: But what is a complete sequence of *covers*? What does it have to do with a complete sequence of *natural numbers*?

Comment: @hartkp a sequence of covers $\mathcal{G}_n$ so that any filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ with $\mathcal{G}_n \cap \mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$ for all $n$ has a cluster point. (I believe Aarts has defined some similar notion in his studies on completeness). I see no relation with the natural numbers sequence.

Comment: @hartkp I have edited my question, thank you for your note. Does it make sense to you now? I have to admit I haven´t worked with some notions before, so it took me more time to study the correct definitions.

Comment: For clarification: when you ask that $S_n$ is discrete, do you mean that for every $x\in X$, $x$ has an open neighborhood that intersects at most one $s\in S_n\subset \mathcal P(X)$?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I thought it should be something like that but the original statement made sense to me in the context of topological spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the countable, hence $\sigma$-discrete, cover $\bigl\{\{q\}\times\mathcal{C}:q\in\mathbb{Q}\bigr\}$ gives a constant sequence that is complete: if a filter intersects the cover then it has a compact element and hence accumulation points.